# error trying to make sandbox paypal to work with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, payment-gateway, activemerchant

I am having problems integrating paypal payment gateway with rails. I will explain below the steps i did.

I first went to **developer.paypal.com**

I created two sandbox accounts one for buyer and one for business account.

I changed business account to Business-Pro

I then installed activemerchant gem in rails.

In config/environments/development.rb i pasted the following chunk

```
  config.after_initialize do
    ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test
    paypal_options = {
      login: "aGthYkgkYXVA_api1.gmail.com",
      password: "DH2RB21WR2EWNSTM",
      signature: "ApBHX2qbpxJW-Ll3oP22LSao0WeuAT.A.uNyDDqIArQeMLYzMTqsZnCW"
    }
    ::GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalGateway.new(paypal_options)
end
```

Then in controller i created a test method and pasted code to do checkout

```
 # ActiveMerchant accepts all amounts as Integer values in cents
        amount = 1000  # $10.00

        # The card verification value is also known as CVV2, CVC2, or CID
        credit_card = ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
                        :brand => 'visa',
                        :first_name         => 'Bob',
                        :last_name          => 'Bobsen',
                        :number             => '4132033791119477',
                        :month              => 3,
                        :year               => 2022,
                        :verification_value => '123')

        # Validating the card automatically detects the card type
        if credit_card.validate.empty?
          # Capture $10 from the credit card
          response = GATEWAY.purchase(amount, credit_card, :ip => '128.1.1.1')

          if response.success?
            puts "Successfully charged $#{sprintf("%.2f", amount / 100)} to the credit card #{credit_card.display_number}"
          else
            raise StandardError, response.message
          end
        end
```

when i execute the controller method i get the following error

> This transaction cannot be processed. The merchant's account is not
>   able to process transactions.

I am wondering the reason for this error.

I used credit card number and exp date from the buyer sandbox account i created above.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Quick one - those credentials _definitely_ all sandbox based yeah? Personally, I'd edit them out regardless :)

Answer (score 0):

It's in their [docs](https://support.picnet.net/hc/en-us/articles/114094053611-Understanding-PayPal-Website-Payments-Pro-error-messages):

> 10548  This transaction cannot be processed. The merchant's account is not able to process transactions.   The merchant account attempting the transaction is not a business account at PayPal. Check your account settings.

-

> 10549  This transaction cannot be processed. The merchant's account is not able to process transactions.   The merchant account attempting the transaction is not able to process Direct Payment transactions. Contact PayPal for more information.

I'd check the status of your account and ensure it's definitely switched to business. Have a poke around it there and let me know how you get on!

Comment: thanks but i have already checked this. i have checked all settings and i dont see any thing i have missed on setting the accounts. is there any problem in my rails implementation?

Comment: There's nothing obvious in there - which line of code is throwing that error? I'd use [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) or similar to poke around in the `GATEWAY` object and its attributes; however, that up there is definitely PayPal's explanation for the error you're getting.