# several errors with sandbox.paypal.com?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to integrate paypal to my web app. I want to use paypal as payment gateway. In the process i am encountering various errors as listed below.

1) I logged into developer.paypal.com. When i click Accounts under Sandbox it lists all sandbox accounts i have. I wanted to delete the unused account but it says "Something went wrong. One or more sandbox accounts could not be deleted. Try again.".

2) I created merchant or business account in developer.paypal.com. I then logged into sandbox.paypal.com using the created business account. In the dashboard page there is Tools at the top. I clicked on it and selected API credentials in order to get the api credentials for paypal integration to my web app. After clicking on it, it redirects me to my official paypal account dashboard page. i.e https://www.paypal.com/myaccount/home

3) Finally another issue i have been facing and of which i have not been able to receive any solution yet is described in detail here. [error trying to make sandbox paypal to work with rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47716164/error-trying-to-make-sandbox-paypal-to-work-with-rails)

So seeing all these issues i am wondering whether sandbox account is full of bugs and cannot be trusted for api integration testing. In that case does one recommend testing with real accounts? but that will be expensive because we need to send real money.

I appreciate any help on this dilemma. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1)  Unfortunately, this is something that tends to happen in their sandbox.  You can try again later and it might work...it might not.

2)  If this happens you should be able to add "sandbox" back into the URL.  So in this case if you change it back to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/myaccount/home then it should load what you're expecting.

3)  Need to see the actual error code that's coming back in the PayPal response to help more on this one.